# Spyder can't run ipython console

Tags: python, ipython, spyder

I using Miniconda and have created *geospatial* environment inside it. All libraries are installed in this environment while *Spyder* is installed in primary/main environment. I am not able to run spyder ipython console  connected to the geospatial environment.  I have even checked [this out](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/wiki/Working-with-packages-and-environments-in-Spyder#the-modular-approach), did exactly the things mentioned there but nothing  works.

[image: ipython console]

[image: preferences]

[image]

Comment: Do you have more than one version of python installed?

Comment: Nope. Just latest Python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) To fix this you need to run the command mentioned in the message shown in our IPython console, i.e.

`conda install spyder-kernels=0.*`

or if you're using conda-forge exclusively, this needs to be

`conda install -c conda-forge spyder-kernels=0.*`

*Note*: This was solved by chatting with the OP in our Gitter channel, but I'm leaving here the answer for completeness.

Comment: Thanks Carlos, it worked like charm. I have even _pinned_ the spyder-kernels-0.2.6 (latest version in 0.*)  to stop Conda from automatically updating it.